# the development server returned 403 react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am doing a react-native based android app following the geeting started tutorials [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)using real android device connected using USB.

When I run react-native run-android it is resulting in error that says development server returned 403 react native

I tried looking it up online but all I could find was that Mcafee blocks the pory 8081, but if that is so how do I change it and make it work.The pictures [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJNTs.jpg) shows what happens when i run"react-native run-android" another picture is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RDsY.jpg).
Any suggestion would help a lot!Thank you!
This smae question was asked earlier too [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143369/development-server-returned-response-error-code-403-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to execute `react-native start` in the same directory where you use `react-native run-android`?

Try to close all your opened node terminals and:

1) run `react-native start`

2) wait until node would open the terminal

3) run `react-native run-android`

Comment: Yes, did this, it doesnt help